# Can't get JavaScript method to validate my HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to use a javascript method to validate my form but it doesn't seem to be working. No dialog box pops up warning me of any errors even if an empty form is submitted. What could be the error?
(Please Note: The JS File has a method defined for a time-stamp that I am currently not using in my form tag. I need some help with calling two functions as well.)

Here's the code:

```js
function setDate() {
  document.getElementById('date').value = new Date();

}

function validateForm() {
  var a = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var b = document.getElementById("contact1").value;
  var blen = b.length;
  var c = document.getElementById("address1").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("stblimit").value;
  var dlen = d.length;
  var e = document.getElementById("creditlimit").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("commission").value;
  var g = document.getElementById("servicecharges").value;
  //DATE var h = document.forms["addRetailer"]["date"].value;


  if (a == null || a == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (b == null || b == "" || blen == 0 || blen > 10 || blen < 10) {
    alert("Enter a valid number");
    return false;
  } else if (c == null || c == "") {
    alert("Primary Address must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (d == null || d == "" || dlen == 0 || dlen < 0) {
    alert("Set Box Top Limit must be filled with a valid number");
    return false;
  } else if (e == null || e == "") {
    alert("Credit Limit must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (f == null || f == "") {
    alert("Commission Percentage must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (g == null || g == "") {
    alert("Service Charges must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script src="formvalidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Register Retailer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Retailer Information</h1>
  <form name="addRetailer" action="RetailerController" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Contact Number 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="contact1" id="contact1"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Contact Number 2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="contact2" id="contact2"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Address Line 1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Address Line 2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="state" id="state"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Pin Code</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="pin" id="pin"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Set Top Box Limit</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="stblimit" id="stblimit" value="0"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Credit Limit</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="creditlimit" id="creditlimit"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Commission Percentage</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="commission" id="commission" value="0.0"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Service Charges</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="servicecharges" id="servicecharges"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Date of Registration</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="date" id="date"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" value="registerCustomer" name="action"></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Register"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>Click

  <a href="mainPage.html"> Home </a>To Return To The Main Screen

</body>

</html>
```

### EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of my Eclipse IDE workspace. My js file and html file aren't in the same sub-folder, although they are under 'Web Content'. Could that be the issue?

[Screenshot of Eclipse IDE Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIZ7i.jpg)

Comment: Have you run this code with the browser's development tools window open (press F12 with the page open) and then looked at the console tab to see any errors?

Comment: the input tag is self-closing, no closing tag needed

Comment: When I try your code, I get the alerts.

Comment: You need to check your js file, is it in the same folder as your html file? That's the only possibility why your alert doesn't pop up

Comment: I believe there is a problem while calling your .js file. It can't be found or you have made an typing mismatch while saving the file or it isn't in the same directory. EDIT: @budiantoip already stated the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have linked your JS file properly.

Looking at your screenshot I noticed you're using Tomcat and Java EE, which follows Unix style syntax for it's directory on the web server.

### Your directory:

```
-Webcontent/
    -WEB-INF/
        +addRetailer
    -JavaScript/
        +validateForm.js
```

So, your HTML file is in WEB-INF which is under Webcontent and the form validator is under javascript, also under webcontent.

There's three solutions I have for this:

1. Move the JavaScript folder into WEB-INF and change the script reference to: "JavaScript/formvalidation.js"
2. Change the script reference to jump 'up' a directory layer using the double-dot'..' which should end up being: "../JavaScript/formvalidator.js"
3. Use HTML5's form validation instead, which doesn't need JavaScript. and is much neater. You can find details on the Mozilla Dev Network [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome, it seems to work for me:

[image]

The only thing that I changed is that I removed the link to the external JS file. It is possible the error is there and preventing your code from running. Check that file.

Comment: No, the OP's code validates the form (as I've shown). The OP said that the external file has code for a timestamp and that he wasn't using that code, but if there is an error in that file, it would prevent other JS from running.

Comment: bro, I did the same thing as he, and it worked fine, meaning there's no error in his external file

Comment: `The JS File has a method defined for a time-stamp that I am currently not using in my form tag. I need some help with calling two functions as well.` he only refers to the function above the provided validation script? Also, I don't see the point in naming an external js file the same as what is trying to accomplish. It is however possible that there is an error in his code in the external file, if he hasn't provided all of his code.

Comment: @Evochrome I'm really not sure what your point is. As you correctly quote, the external file isn't being used right now, but is still being referenced. The name is not really relevant. His form has an onsubmit=return validateform, which is in the file and provided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus A `method` isn't the same thing as a `file` ;)

Comment: I didn't say it was :)

Comment: In that case, I don't see what you mean. He says that he isn't using the function to get the date in his external file(which is: `function setDate()
{
    document.getElementById('date').value = new Date();
}`), not meaning that is isn't using the other function `validateForm()`.

Comment: Is it really working in chrome ? I've tried on my computer but with no luck.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check the screenshot